# How to export Mudblazor DataGrid Rows as csv file using Button in each row

Tags: datagrid, mudblazor

I am working with the MudBlazor framework and have implemented a DataGrid component to display tabular data on a web page. Each row in the DataGrid contains a Button component.

I would like to provide a functionality where, upon clicking the Button in a row, the data from that specific row is exported and saved as a CSV file. This CSV file should include the relevant information from the clicked row.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Razor component called personlist.razor with the following code:

```
@page "/personlist"
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
<MudDataGrid Items="Persons" Filterable="false" SortMode="@SortMode.None" Groupable="false">
<Columns>
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Age" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Email" />
    <TemplateColumn CellClass="d-flex justify-end">
        <CellTemplate>
            <MudButton Size="@Size.Small" Variant="@Variant.Filled" Color="@Color.Primary" OnClick="@(()=> DownloadAsCsv((Person)context.Item))">Download</MudButton>
        </CellTemplate>
    </TemplateColumn>
</Columns>
```

Add the below code in the @code block

```
@code {

private List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    Persons = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person { Name = "Kiran", Age = 30, Email = "Kiran@example.com" },
        new Person { Name = "john", Age = 25, Email = "john@example.com" },
       new Person { Name = "manu", Age = 25, Email = "manu@example.com" },
    };
}
 private async Task DownloadAsCsv(Person person)
 {
    await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("DownloadAsCsv", person.Name, person.Age, person.Email);
 }
}
```

Add the below javascript in either index.html or _Layout.cshtml/_Host.cshtml

```
<script>
    function DownloadAsCsv(name, Age,Email) {
        var csv = name + "," + Age + "," + Email + "\n";
        var bytes = new TextEncoder().encode(csv);
        var blob = new Blob([bytes], { type: "text/csv" });
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url;
        link.download = name + ".csv";
        link.click();
    }
</script>
```

Person class with properties Name, Age, and Email:

```
 public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).